# how to change order of html elements inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a carousel with three cards

one - previous card
two- active card
three - next card

when the user click next button, the carousel should show the next card as active card and show the elements related to that card including the paragraph(which I have hidden by display:none) and when user click on the back button, the carousel should show the previous card as the active card. Is there any way to achieve this using JavaScript in a easy way.

[Here is the carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdMTg.png)

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.section--black{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 60px 0;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 700px;
}
.slider{
  width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.sliderbox{
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 290px;
    height: 340px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.sliderbox__content .sliderbox__paragraph{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.sliderbox--active .sliderbox__content h2{
    font-size: 32px;
}
.sliderbox__content h2{
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.sliderbox a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.small__heading{
    padding: 10px 0;
}


.sliderbox--prev{
  
  background-image: linear-gradient(black, black), url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/04/06/06/44/astronaut-4106766_960_720.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: saturation;
  margin-right: 35px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  
}

.sliderbox--active{
    min-height: 465px;
    min-width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/14/13/23/ocean-3605547_960_720.jpg');
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.sliderbox--next{
  background-image: linear-gradient(black, black), url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/17/01/39/mystery-1599527_960_720.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: saturation;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 70px;

}
.sliderbox--active .sliderbox__content{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -44%;
}


.slider__arrows{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.slider__arrow{
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slider__arrow:first-child{
  margin-right: 20px; 
}


.slider__overflow{
  right: -100%;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}


.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f92ec5af05.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <title>slider</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="slider_section section--black">
        <div class="container">
      <div id="slider" class="slider">
            <div class="sliderbox sliderbox--prev">
                <div class="sliderbox__content">
                    <h2>Industry Ready Program</h2>
                    <p class="small__heading">Get Ready to Work</p>
          <p class="sliderbox__paragraph hidden">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                    <a href="">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sliderbox sliderbox--active">
                <div class="sliderbox__content">
                    <h2>Industry Program</h2>
                    <p class="small__heading">Get Perspective</p>
                    <p class="sliderbox__paragraph">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                    <a href="">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sliderbox sliderbox--next">
                <div class="sliderbox__content">
                    <h2>Industry Ready Program</h2>
                    <p class="small__heading">Get Ready to Work</p>
          <p class="sliderbox__paragraph hidden">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                    <a href="">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>

        <div id="data-carousel" class="slider">
            <div class="sliderbox sliderbox--prev">
                <div class="sliderbox__content">
                    <h2>Industry Ready Program</h2>
                    <p class="small__heading">Get Ready to Work</p>
          <p class="sliderbox__paragraph hidden">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                    <a href="">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sliderbox sliderbox--active">
                <div class="sliderbox__content">
                    <h2>Industry Program</h2>
                    <p class="small__heading">Get energised</p>
                    <p class="sliderbox__paragraph">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                    <a href="">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sliderbox sliderbox--next">
                <div class="sliderbox__content">
                    <h2>Industry Ready Program</h2>
                    <p class="small__heading">Get Ready to Work</p>
          <p class="sliderbox__paragraph hidden">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
                        it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                    <a href="">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>

            <div class="slider__arrows">
            <i id="prev" class="slider__arrow slider__arrow--prev fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i>
      <i id="next" class=" slider__arrow slider__arrow--prev fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
        </div>

        </div>





    </section>
  <footer>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </footer>

    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this below code help you, this is simple slide show (do same coding with hidden class)    (Use full screen Snippet)

```js
const next = document.querySelector("#next")
const prev = document.querySelector("#prev")
const slider = document.querySelectorAll(".sliderbox")


let countIndex = 0
next.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (slider.length - 1 > countIndex) {
    countIndex++
    slider[`${countIndex - 1}`].classList.remove("active")
    slider[countIndex].classList.add("active")
  } else {
    countIndex = 0
    slider[slider.length - 1].classList.remove("active")
    slider[countIndex].classList.add("active")
  }
})
prev.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (countIndex === 0) {
    countIndex = slider.length - 1
    slider[0].classList.remove("active")
    slider[countIndex].classList.add("active")
  }
  countIndex--
  slider[`${countIndex + 1}`].classList.remove("active")
  slider[countIndex].classList.add("active")
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.section--black {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 700px;
}
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.sliderbox {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 290px;
  height: 340px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.sliderbox__content .sliderbox__paragraph {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.sliderbox--active .sliderbox__content h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
}
.sliderbox__content h2 {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.sliderbox a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.small__heading {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.sliderbox {
  background-image: linear-gradient(black, black), url("#");
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: saturation;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}
.sliderbox.active {
  min-height: 465px;
  min-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("#");
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.sliderbox.active .sliderbox__content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -44%;
}

.slider__arrows {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.slider__arrow {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slider__arrow:first-child {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.slider__overflow {
  right: -100%;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f92ec5af05.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <title>slider</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="slider_section section--black">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="slider" class="slider">
          <div class="sliderbox">
            <div class="sliderbox__content">
              <h2>Industry Ready Program</h2>
              <p class="small__heading">Get Ready to Work</p>
              <p class="sliderbox__paragraph hidden">
                is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
                since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
                and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
              </p>
              <a href="">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sliderbox">
            <div class="sliderbox__content">
              <h2>Industry Program</h2>
              <p class="small__heading">Get Perspective</p>
              <p class="sliderbox__paragraph">
                is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
                since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
                and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
              </p>
              <a href="">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sliderbox">
            <div class="sliderbox__content">
              <h2>Industry Ready Program</h2>
              <p class="small__heading">Get Ready to Work</p>
              <p class="sliderbox__paragraph hidden">
                is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
                since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
                and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
              </p>
              <a href="">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
       

          <div class="sliderbox">
            <div class="sliderbox__content">
              <h2>Industry Ready Program</h2>
              <p class="small__heading">Get Ready to Work</p>
              <p class="sliderbox__paragraph hidden">
                is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
                since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
                and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
              </p>
              <a href="">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sliderbox">
            <div class="sliderbox__content">
              <h2>Industry Program</h2>
              <p class="small__heading">Get energised</p>
              <p class="sliderbox__paragraph">
                is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
                since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
                and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
              </p>
              <a href="">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sliderbox">
            <div class="sliderbox__content">
              <h2>Industry Ready Program</h2>
              <p class="small__heading">Get Ready to Work</p>
              <p class="sliderbox__paragraph hidden">
                is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
                since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
                and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
              </p>
              <a href="">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     
        <div class="slider__arrows">
          <i
            id="prev"
            class="slider__arrow slider__arrow--prev fa-solid fa-arrow-left"
          ></i>
          <i
            id="next"
            class="slider__arrow slider__arrow--prev fa-solid fa-arrow-right"
          ></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a carousel in a simple way you can try this:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

.mySlides {
  display: none
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://img.lemde.fr/2019/05/17/0/0/3553/2542/664/0/75/0/74a2a9f_91ae3c37d18b44d4ae49147a7b9a2126-91ae3c37d18b44d4ae49147a7b9a2126-0.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://img.lemde.fr/2019/05/17/0/0/3553/2542/664/0/75/0/74a2a9f_91ae3c37d18b44d4ae49147a7b9a2126-91ae3c37d18b44d4ae49147a7b9a2126-0.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Without running your code in a Stack Snippet `<>` I would have never have known it works. Make sure to include a snippet when you can, and could expand further by adding absolute image file paths to demonstrate it working.

Comment: @Kameron okay thank you. i will do it next time